# Am I in trouble if I used beautiful soup to get data from google.com?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I used -

```
URL = "http://www.google.com"
r = requests.get(URL)
  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib') 
print(soup.prettify())
```

I was learning python and did not know that web scraping is not allowed.

Comment: It also depends on what you did with the results. Did you sell them to the Russians, or to Microsoft?

Comment: Web scraping is allowed. But if you abuse it you'll have your IP address blocked. No one is going to come knocking at your door

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No

Google doesn't allow web scraping, but they don't take any legal action against it. They use a lot of defense systems, so even if you tried to do something bad it would just be blocked.

Just don't worry about it :)